# Printing in SIGALRM handler

Tags: c, process, fork

While messing around with system calls for a class, I ran into trouble with the following code. For whatever reason, when the print statement in the signal handler has a newline at the end of it, it behaves as intended, with the signal being received and handled and the message being displayed. However, when the newline is *not* present, no output is shown at all.

I'm at a loss as to why this might be the case, and was hoping someone could shed some light on the issue.

Further, when it *does* print something, the signal only seems to be being sent four times? All sorts of strange things with this code.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void alarm_handler(int signo) {
    printf("pid : %d\n", getpid());
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    pid_t pid;
    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);

    pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0)
        while(1) { }
    else
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            sleep(1);
            kill(pid, SIGALRM);
        }  
        kill(pid, SIGKILL);
    }
}
```

GCC Version information

```
gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer//usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: I am not sure it is the issue.  But you should not use `printf()` in the signal handler as it is not `async-signal-safe functions`.  For a list of functions, please see [signal man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).  You should try to replace the `printf()` with `write()`.

Comment: Also, to see the printf from your fifth signal, move the `sleep(1)` line after `kill(pid, SIGALRM)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you for whatever reason want to display something printed without end of line it will most likely help to do `fflush(stdout);` as stdout is buffered and normally flushes at each end of line.

Answer (score 2):

1. As pointed out by [*Henrik Carlqvist*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4134321/henrik-carlqvist) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28135959/694576), you observer the effect of  "buffered output".
2. Also [*SCC*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1865106/ssc) mentions in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135657/printing-in-sigalrm-handler/28136575?noredirect=1#comment44643859_28135657) that `printf()` isn't async signal safe and shall not be called form a signal handler.

To get around 1. and fullfil 2. just write your message using the signal safe function [`write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), which moreover use **un**buffered I/O, so no flushing is needed.

```
void alarm_handler(int signo) 
{
  char msg[64] = "alarm handler called";
  /* snprintf(msg, sizeof msg, "pid : %d\n", getpid()); */ /* sprintf also isn't async signal safe */
  write(fileno(stdout), msg, strlen(msg));      
}
```

Comment: Avoiding calls to functions not safely called from a signal handler is the way to go. As pointed out by alk and SSC printf is not in the list of signal safe functions. Unfortunately also other nice functions like sprintf is missing in that list. You might want to implement your own itoa function (google might give you an exemple of existing code) to use with write.

Comment: Got me! :} @HenrikCarlqvist